# Multiple User Messages on list Validation Settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, administration, validation

Is there any OOB way to display different user message per validation?

Comment: Hi @Damian, did you check my answer below? Let me know if you still need any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, No.

You cannot add multiple user messages on list validation settings. You will have to combine all the validation messages in the single text box as validation message is a simple text input.

**Documentation**: [Validation element (List)](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/schema/validation-element-list?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

[image]

---

**Additional**:

If you have any validation which will use only single column value in formula, consider using the **column validation** under column settings - here you can add different validation user message:

[image]

**Note**: If your formula/condition is using multiple column values, you will have to use the "list validation" only as column validation does not support reading values from another columns in the formula conditions.